# inequality measures for comparing two distributions

Tags: inequality

I am looking for an inequality measure to compare the inequality between two distributions. The random variable is categorical and I am thinking of using Gini index and skewness. Here is my two questions:

- I read in a paper that skewness is a shape measure and Gini is not. Does Gini tell us anything about the shape of the distribution? What is the benefit of each of these measures in that sense?
- I am looking to compare the two distributions in terms of inequality. To give an example, if we have the distribution of two societies, can we use Gini and skewness in order to compare them although we know that the number of classes of two societies (number of categories)  are not close at all e.g. one has 10 classes and one has 40? Is skewness bounded? Can it be used for comparison?

Comment: Perhaps better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: You are on the right track. Gini measures dispersion and is equivalent to half the mean absolute difference according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient. That may be correlated with skewness which relates directly to shape determined by variation of number of observations. Another interesting measure is the KS test which was designed to compare distributions for equality, provided they are continuous and one dimensional, however several approaches have been developed for extending it to multivariate distributions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Smirnov_test.

Comment: I am not looking for measuring equality (distance) between distribution A and B (which KS seems to do). I am trying to compare the inequalities for each distribution e.g. the inequality of distribution A is 0.3 and for B is 0.5. By inequality I mean the fairness of distribution e.g. poverty and income in societies A and B.